# Leer imagen RAW en Opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv

Necesito leer una imagen en formato raw en Opencv para aplicarle después diversas modificaciones (balance de grises, contornos, etc...) ¿Hay alguna manera de leer ese formato directamente desde Opencv, o de convertirla en alguno compatible, como jpg o bmp?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a S.O en español. Te invito a que realices el recorrido, mires como preguntar y así ganes tu primera medalla.

Comment: `Mat imagen = imread("imagen.raw");`